# Access Denied on image styles images with private file system

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-8, http-status-code-403

Image upload is private. Images are being accessed through `/system/files/` path. But on accessing the private images with image styles in `/system/files/styles/` path I'm getting access denied.

I have tried this solution, but it did not work. Please share if there is any other way.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sites/.*/files/private/styles/
RewriteRule ^/core/authorize.php/core/authorize.php(.*)$ /core/authorize.php$1`

Comment: If you've made the folder protected, the browser won't be able to access them, even if it's through CSS

Comment: All the files that are upload are also in the private folder, those are accessible for logged in users but not for anonymous that is how it is suppose to be. But when I'm applying image style on them, files are generated but not accessible for logged in users also.